# Getting value through DOM and then filter an array for the value returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have written a function which is supposed to filter through an array and return a value associated with the given value. For example, by knowing a name, I want to get the initials.

## array

```
let members = [
    {
        id: 1,
        memberFullName: "Ben Stiller",
        memberInitials: "BS"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        memberFullName: "Michael Jackson",
        memberInitials: "MJ"
    }
];
```

## function

```
function findMemberInitials(object) {
    let result = members.filter( obj => {
        return obj.memberFullName == object;
    })[0].memberInitials;
}
```

When I run the array like findMemberInitials("Ben Stiller"); it returns BS as expected.

When I try to get the value from at user input first and then run it through the function, it returns undefined.

```
let getMemberName = document.getElementById("name").value;
let getMemberInitials = findMemberInitials(getMemberName);

console.log(getMemberInitials); //returns undefined.
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I've tried parsing it to a string, but it didn't help.

Comment: there is no return in findMemberInitials

Comment: And you're not returning anything from your function, you need to return result from your function

Comment: If no member has been found your function will throw an error.

Comment: In addition to adding a return, I would change the parameter name to something meaningful because `object` is not very meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from function. Secondly you should use `find()`

```js
let members = [
    {
        id: 1,
        memberFullName: "Ben Stiller",
        memberInitials: "BS"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        memberFullName: "Michael Jackson",
        memberInitials: "MJ"
    }
];

function findMemberInitials(object) {
    return (members.find(obj => obj.memberFullName === object) || {}).memberInitials;
}

console.log(findMemberInitials("Michael Jackson"))
```

Comment: Returning null is better than returning an empty object.

Comment: @CodingYoshi `{}.memberInitials` will return `undefined` but `null.memberInitials` will throw error.

Comment: You need to check if anything was found before calling `memberInitial` on it. If nothing is found, return null.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I think this way is fine. returning `undefined` or `null` doesn't make much difference